# Iterating over collection from $.getJSON and pushing new objects into an array leaves array empty

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json

I am getting some json data from a remote url and iterating over each item in the collection and in the process creating new objects from the data and pushing them into a new array

```
function getPoints(year) {

    var heatmapdata = [];

    var promise = $.getJSON('/api/GetHeatMapData?nodeid=@UmbracoContext.PageId&year=' + year);

    promise.done(function (data) {
        $.each(data, function (i, item) {
            heatmapdata.push({ location: new google.maps.LatLng(item.Location.lat, item.Location.lng), weight: item.Weight });
        });
    });

    return heatmapdata;
}
```

In my browser (Chrome) I stick a breakpoint on the return line it says the array length is zero. In my browser console if I call `getPoints(2010)` it returns []. If I stick a break point on the line below I can see that items are being pushed into the array:

```
heatmapdata.push({ location: new google.maps.LatLng(item.Location.lat, item.Location.lng), weight: item.Weight });
```

I've been wresting with this for a long time and concerned I am missing something obvious?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Dr. GIT alludes to, this is happening because `$.getJSON` is an asynchronous function.

When javascript encounters an asynchronous function, the steps inside it are run in the background so to speak and javascript does not wait for those steps to complete before running the rest of the code in the block.

Basically, you can't use `return` with an asynchronous function.

Currently, your function is called, it fires off `$.getJSON`, then immediately returns `heatmapdata` which is still an empty array, in the background, `heatmapdata` is being filled but you dont do anything with it when it's finished.

There are several ways you could fix this. One would be to provide a callback function as shown below which will be called after your promise has been resolved. (You could also move the code to the .done function, use another promise, or use $.Deffered)

```
function getPoints(year, callback) {
    var heatmapdata = [];
    var promise = $.getJSON('/api/GetHeatMapData?nodeid=@UmbracoContext.PageId&year=' + year);
    promise.done(function (data) {
        $.each(data, function (i, item) {
            heatmapdata.push({
                location: new google.maps.LatLng(item.Location.lat, item.Location.lng),
                weight: item.Weight
            });
        });
        callback(heatmapdata);
    });
}

getPoints(year, function(heatmapdata ){ 
   // do something with heatmapdata here  
});
```

Comment: Thanks for point out my now obvious mistake, always the most obvious things are the hardest for me to spot.

Answer (score 1):

I think it is because of the promises. So the return Statement is called before the promise is executed.